# Make [tag:electrics] a synonym for [tag:electrical]?

Tags: discussion

There is no description for [electrics](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electrics) so I could be way off base here, but it seems like it is the British English version of [electrical](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electrical) and that it would make sense to set them up as synonyms.

Comment: Yes, completely agree